# can I run ROS2 and ROS1 on one ubuntu at the same time?

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,

on my ubuntu 16.04, I already have a ros1 system setup and up running. however, I need to launch a separate ros2 node at the same time. when I source the /opt/ros/$ros_version/setup.bash, it seems the system can only allow one version of ros up running. I am wondering how I could run ros1 and ros2 simultaneously?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355548/can-i-run-ros2-and-ros1-on-one-ubuntu-at-the-same-time?/) by [pidan101](https://answers.ros.org/users/56001/pidan101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2020-06-22**:\

> it seems the system can only allow one version of ros up running

Is there a specific error message? ROS 1 and ROS 2 can definitely be run at the same time. This is how the ros1 bridge works:

https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2020-06-23**:
Note that ROS2 requires (or at least is prebuild for) at least Ubuntu 18.04. One solution I'm using right now is to install a ROS2 Docker image - I'm currently running Foxy in a Ubuntu 18.04 Docker container (built from source as Foxy is only offered for 20.04+) with ROS1 running `rosbag play` in the base 16.04. (In VSCode's terminal running on Windows+Remote SSH plugin)

**Comment by [pidan101](https://answers.ros.org/users/56001/pidan101/) on 2020-06-23**:
thanks! very helpful. but to clarify, ROS2 has, for example, ardent, which can run perfectly on ubuntu 16.04. why do you say it requires at least 18.04? thanks

**Comment by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) on 2020-06-23**:
`ardent` is quite old, but I was thinking of the versions I've worked on, `eloquent` (18.04) and `foxy` (20.04); looking at the [ROS Docker repo](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/tree/master/ros) `ardent` is the only one offered for 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use multiple terminals / sessions. You can certainly have multiple versions of ROS running but you should make sure to only source the one required in each terminal before running a launch / run command.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5